# Checker Framework reporting in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checker-framework

How can I configure so that warnings that are issued by the Checker Framework are picked up and reported in Jenkins (e.g. by using the [Analysis Collector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Analysis+Collector+Plugin))?

For the record, I am using maven and the [checkersplugin](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checkers-manual.html#maven-plugin) with the `<failOnError>` configuration set to `false`, and the Checker Framework warnings are displayed in the console output in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not required to use a special Jenkins plugin such as Analysis Collector.

The Checker Framework issues warnings and errors that are identical to those of javac (because the Checker Framework is a plug-in to javac).  Therefore, whatever mechanism you already use to make Jenkins report compiler warnings and errors will work for the Checker Framework.

As a tip, if you are using the -Awarns command-line argument to treat pluggable type-checking errors as warnings, then you will also want to configure the Jenkins task as follows:  Set "post-build actions" to "scan for compiler warnings", with parser "Java compiler".

Comment: Kind of works, however I see "_warning: incompatible types in assignment_" in the "Java Warnings" in Jenkins, whereas the console also shows "_could not parse error message: found : @ReadOnly Class<T extends @ReadOnly Object> required: @Mutable Class<T extends @Mutable Object>_"? 
I also tried to set `<javacParams>-Awarns -Xmaxwarns 10000</javacParams>` (and removed `<failOnError>false</failOnError>`), but that caused the compiler to output errors instead of warnings?

Comment: An [issue](http://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/issues/detail?id=177) was filed that described the disability to turn of compiler errors using the `-Awarns` flag.